# Firebase : retrieve data using for another retrieve datas

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have form key so ı want to take all form's values and you can see "who" value. Than I want to  use this "who" value for user's information. I tried this with observable but ı couldn't. How can ı do this ? and How can ı combine this datas ?

items2: Observable< any>;

items3: Observable< any>;

```
test1(key){
    
    this.items2 = this.db.object('forms/'+key).valueChanges();
    this.items2.forEach(x=>{this.items3=this.db.object('users/'+x.who).valueChanges()})
  }
```

this is my firebase database :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
test(key): void {
    this.db.object('forms').snapshotChanges().subscribe(l => {
      const k = l.payload.child(key);
      const kj = k.val();
      const nextrecord = kj.who
      console.log(kj.who);
      this.db.object('users').snapshotChanges().subscribe(n => {
        const nm = n.payload.child(nextrecord);
        console.log(nm.val());
      })
    })
  }
```

Comment: I modify my answer, and change this 'users/'+ p.who for real id like 'users/biFA....' if You receive any data we make think something more, and try get only data from first element like in my answer.

Comment: Is what you want ?